# For looping several thousands of Url apis and adding it to a list

Tags: python, json, api, rest, brute-force

Problem: The output of this code seems to be repeating alot of the same entries in the final list, thus making it exponentially  longer.

The goal would be complete the query and the print the final list with all city within the region

```
[
    {
        "name": "Herat",
        "id": "AF~HER~Herat"
    }
]
[
    {
        "name": "Herat",
        "id": "AF~HER~Herat"
    },
    {
        "name": "Kabul",
        "id": "AF~KAB~Kabul"
    }
]
[
    {
        "name": "Herat",
        "id": "AF~HER~Herat"
    },
    {
        "name": "Kabul",
        "id": "AF~KAB~Kabul"
    },
    {
        "name": "Kandahar",
        "id": "AF~KAN~Kandahar"
    }
]
```

My goal is to to a get a list with cityID. I first to a GET request and parse the JSON response to get the country IDs to a list,

Second: I have a for loop, which will make another GET request for the region id, but i now need to add the country IDs to the api url. I do that by adding .format on the GET request. and iterate trough all the countries and there respective region IDs, i parse them and store them in a list.

Third: i have another for loop, which will make another GET request for the cityID that will loop trough all cities with the above Region ID list, and the respectively collect the cityID that i really need.

Code :

```
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
import requests
import json
import urllib3

urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)

def countries():
    data = requests.get("https://localhost/api/netim/v1/countries/", verify=False, auth=HTTPBasicAuth("admin", "admin"))
    rep = data.json()
    a = []
    for elem in rep['items']:
        a.extend([elem.get("id","")])
    print(a)
    return a
def regions():
    ids = []
    for c in countries():
        url = requests.get("https://localhost/api/netim/v1/countries/{}/regions".format(c), verify=False, auth=HTTPBasicAuth("admin", "admin"))
        response = url.json()
        for cid in response['items']:
            ids.extend([cid.get("id","")])
        data = []
        for r in ids:
            url = requests.get("https://localhost/api/netim/v1/regions/{}/cities".format(r), verify=False, auth=HTTPBasicAuth("admin", "admin"))
            response = url.json()
            data.extend([{"name":r.get("name",""),"id":r.get("id", "")} for r in response['items']])
        print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))
    return data
regions()

print(regions())
```

You will see thou output contains several copies of the same entry.

Not a programmer, not sure where am i getting it wrong

Comment: It looks like you are resetting "data" in the regions function each iteration of the countries. Does that print after that show different countries each time? It looks like it only returns the last country due to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks as though the output you're concerned with might be due to the fact that you're printing `data` as you iterate through it in the `regions()` method.

Try to remove the line:
`print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))`?

Also, and more importantly - you're setting `data` to an empty list every time you iterate on an item in Countries.  You should probably declare that variable before the initial loop.

You're already printing the final result when you call the function.  So printing as you iterate only really makes sense if you're debugging & needing to review the data as you go through it.